# ¿Cómo mantengo el color de mi dropdown-menu luego de darle click?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Desearía saber ¿cómo puedo mantener el color original de un dropdownMenu ya que antes de clickear el menú se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego al clickear se observa de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, si no realizo ninguna opción y simplemente regreso el menú presionándolo de nuevo cambia de color y se visualiza gris:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo lograr que regrese siempre a su azul natural? Esto ocurre solo cuando lo regreso ya que si yo lo clickeo y luego hago click en otra parte del portal en ese momento si retiene el color azul, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Éste es mi código HTML

```css
ul.nav { 
  display:table; width:100%; 
}

ul.nav > li { 
  display:table-cell; float:none;
}

ul.nav > li > a { 
  background-color: #006699;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.nav > li > a > h4 { 
  color:white;
}

h4 { 
  color:white !important;
}

.navbar-header {
  margin: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  float:none;
}

a:hover{
  background-color: #99ccff !important
}

.page-header h1 {
  color: #ff9900;
  font-family: 'Lobster';
}

.page-header h1:hover {
  color: #0099ff;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  background-color: #006699 !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse "  >
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
          <h4 >MENU <b class="caret"></b></h4>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #006699" >
          <li class="dropdown-header" ><a href="#" ><h4>PRODUCTOS</h4></a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#"><h4>Cambiar Email</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><h4>Cambiar Password</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><h4>Logout</h4></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" ><a href="index - copia.html"><h4> INICIO</h4></a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ><a href="varon.html"><h4> LOCATION</h4></a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ><a href="dama.html"><h4> CONTACTANOS</h4></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

Lo más probable es que el estilo de Bootstrap esté siendo aplicado, tal vez con la pseudoclase `:focus` o alguna otra, te doy una idea del código que debes buscar en el css de Bootstrap para que hagas el 'override' respectivo, sin modificar bootstrap:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

O tal vez:

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema surge cuando el elemento **a** adquiere el foco (el cursor del teclado se encuentra sobre el elemento). Para corregir el error, debes asignar las mismas propiedades que quieres conservar al elemento a, empleando la pseudoclase "focus".

De este modo, tu código en las líneas 9 a 12 quedaría así:

```
ul.nav > li > a, ul.nav > li > a:focus { 
  background-color: #006699;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias problema solucionado!

Comment: @AlejandroRuiz, si la respuesta te fue útil, ¿podrías marcarla como respuesta correcta? Así todo el mundo sabrá que la pregunta ya está contestada.